# Unable to get youtube-player working in Angular 17 cause of NG0203: inject() er

Tags: angular, youtube, youtube-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtEPq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mt7ws.png)

Tried adding youtube api script to index html like the video said but the page is still not rendering the video.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHblO.png)
Here is the video used to create a simple youtube-player element.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JepMpjhkt-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NqIr.png)

Comment: what angular version are you using?

Comment: You probably have a duplicated instance of `@angular/core`. Can you do a `npm ls @angular/core`

Comment: @Andrei its angular 17

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler , yes that is the case. Is there a way to remove the dupes? I added a picture to the question.

Comment: Actually after deleting the whole node modules folder, package-lock, doing an npm-cache clean then reinstall I was able to get it to work. Thank you!